# How to place certain rows in specific position in resultset, postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

consider table with events:

```
| date         | name       | wanted position| 
----------------------------------------
| 01.01.2001   | game       | 
| 01.02.2001   | game       | 
| 01.03.2001   | game       | 
| 01.04.2001   | game       | 
| 01.05.2001   | tournament | 3
| 01.06.2001   | game       |
```

Now I fetch events from the table ordered by date. Works fine, but with large amount of rows tournament is somewhere in the end of list. So, no one actually sees it. To solve that, I want to put tournament be always on third (or any other arbitrary position depending on situation) position in the resultset if tournament date is after date of actual event on desired position.

For example these are resultsets I'd like to have:

1-> tournament is on third position event though it is later in the list if ordered by date

```
| date         | name       | wanted position| 
----------------------------------------
| 01.01.2001   | game       | 
| 01.02.2001   | game       | 
| 01.05.2001   | tournament | 3
| 01.03.2001   | game       | 
| 01.04.2001   | game       | 
| 01.06.2001   | game       |
```

2-> tournament is on second position because date is already close and natural order by date works just fine

```
| date         | name       | wanted position| 
----------------------------------------
| 01.04.2001   | game       | 
| 01.05.2001   | tournament | 3
| 01.06.2001   | game       | 
| 01.07.2001   | game       | 
| 01.08.2001   | game       |
```

Is that doable somehow with SQL? Database is postgresql.

Comment: Do you have a `wanted position` column in the table?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily always make it first:

```
select t.*
from t
order by (name = 'tournament')::int desc,
         date;
```

Making it third is a bit trickier.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `row_number()` within a case expression, like this:

```
SELECT
    date, name
FROM (
    SELECT
        date
      , name
      , CASE
            WHEN name = 'tournament' THEN 3
            ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date DESC)
        END rn
    FROM mytable
) d
order by rn, name DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting. This looks like a move to right direction, but I did not study this any futher and implemented feature on application level because it seem to be way too complex to have that feature somehow done on SQL layer.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. It is a "presentation layer" type of requirement so I don't disagree with your decision. I'm so very comfortable with SQL that I don't see a case expression with row_number() being complex, but "each to their own" as the saying goes. Cheers.